# Scrape table data using pandas/beautiful soup (instead of selenium which is slow?), BS implementation not working

Tags: pandas, selenium, numpy, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape web data on this website, and the only way I was able to access the data was by iterating through the rows of the table, adding them to a list (then adding them to a pandas data frame/writing to a csv), and then clicking to the next page and repeating the process [there are about 50 pages per search and my program does 100+ searches]. It's super slow/inefficient, and I was wondering if there was a way to efficiently add all the data using pandas or beautiful soup instead of iterating through each line/column.

url = "https://claimittexas.org/app/claim-search"

```
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody/tr")
    try:
        for row in rows[1:]:
            row_array = []
            #print(row.text) # prints the whole row
            for col in row.find_elements_by_xpath('td')[1:]:
                row_array.append(col.text.strip())
            table_array.append(row_array)
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_array)
        df.to_csv('my_csv.csv', mode='a', header=False)
    except:
        print(letters + "no table exists")
```

**EDIT: I tried to scrape using beautiful soup, something I tried earlier in the week and posted about, but I can't seem to access the table without using selenium**

With the bs version, I put a bunch of print statements in to see what was wrong, and it has that the rows value is just an empty list

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
rows = soup.find('table').find('tbody').find_all(('tr')[1:])
for row in rows[1:]:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    for cell in cells[1:]:
        print(cell.get_text())
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium ChromeDriver: increasing time of getting WebElement Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50097877/selenium-chromedriver-increasing-time-of-getting-webelement-text)

Comment: You can use response to get the HTML text and parse it locally and then use the way you want. believe me, it would be way faster than the way you are trying to do using selenium

Comment: @min2bro how would I do that?

Comment: @ss77 Share the URL that you want to parse, Let me take a look..

Comment: @min2bro thanks so much, it's in the post but here it is - url = "https://claimittexas.org/app/claim-search"

Answer (score 0):

use this line in BS4 code implimentation

```
rows = soup.find('table').find('tbody').find_all('tr')[1:]
```

instead of

```
rows = soup.find('table').find('tbody').find_all(('tr')[1:])
```